# Fibres of square map on finite groups and the inverse set of a subset

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group and $q:G\rightarrow G:g\mapsto g^2$ the square map. Now, if $A$ is a subset of one fibre of $q$, i. e.
$$a^2=b^2$$
holds for all $a,b\in A$, is there always some $g\in G$ such that
$$gA=A^{-1}\,\,?$$
(note: $gA:=\{ga|a\in A\}$ is simply the left-translate of the set $A\subseteq G$ with the element $g\in G$.)
Calculations with GAP for groups up to order 60 support this conjecture, however I was unable to prove it and actually I'm not convinced that it holds for larger groups. Some related well-known (http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Square_map) facts are:

The mapping $q$ is bijective iff $2\not|\, |G|$. (So only groups of even order are interesting w.r.t our question.)

The mapping $q$ is a homomorphism iff $G$ is Abelian. (However I'm interested in the non-Abelian case as well.)

Comment: Being in the same orbit suggests an action. Which action are you using here?

Comment: Is it the adjoint action $g\cdot a = gag^{-1}?$

Comment: Sorry, for the confusion, I simply mean the left regular action, so $g\cdot A^{-1}$ means the group multiplication. I've clearified it in the original post.

Comment: I don't think that is an action: I don't think that if $a^{2} = b^{2},$ we need have $(ga)^{2} = (gb)^{2}.$ For example, take $G = S_{3}$, $a= (12),b= (13), g = (12).$ In other words, the translation of a fiber by a group element need not be a fiber. You need to explain more what you really intend.

Comment: @ Geoff: Sure we won't have $(ga)^2=(gb)^2$ in general, but it's not what I mean anyway. $a^2=b^2$ for all $a,b\in A$ is just a property of the subset $A\subseteq G$. I don't claim at all that $gA$ (by which I mean the left-translate of the subset $A\subseteq G$ with the element $g$) has this property as well. I've restated my question without using the terms "orbit" or "action". Maybe that makes it more straight.

Comment: Won't $g=a^{-2}$ do it?

Comment: Jeremy's comment solves my question:
We fix $a_0\in A$ arbitrarily and put $g:=a_0^{-2}$. Then
$$gA=a_0^{-2}A=A^{-1},
$$because $a_0^2=a^2$ for all $a\in A$ implies $a_0^{-2}=a^{-2}$, thus $a_0^{-2}a=a^{-1}$ for all $a\in A$.

Thanks Jeremy! (I cannot answer my own question due to lack of reputation. Could someone close this thread, please?)